# How to make the search bar in your website searching for products and showing the thing you searching about

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I want to know how to make my search bar on my blog website working like amazon or any website have a search bar when you type a letter it shows you things related to the letter you searched for and the things that I mean it is something like a blog or product

Comment: I would suggest you look into "fuzzy search".

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for such a broad question.

Comment: Check Algolia. but yeah, broad question mate.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with vanilla JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {

  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li, h4 {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>


<div class="dropdown">

  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    
    <h4>My List</h4>
    <ul>
    <li id="product1">Car</li>
    <li id="product2">Bicyle</li>
    <li id="product3">Motocycle</li>
    <li id="product4">Boat</li>
    <li id="product5">Lawn Mower</li>
    <li id="product6">Trailer</li>
    <li id="product7">Power Saw</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* Javascript function to search the list*/
function filterFunction() {
  let input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  /* change everything to lower or upper case in order 
  to make the search case insensitive */
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); 
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  li = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    txtValue = li[i].textContent || li[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```